# Can you explain what this binary swapping operation is doing?

Tags: c++, encryption, encoding

I'm currently trying to solve this programing [programing puzzle](https://www.codingame.com/ide/2131287c90786f4f4000d013010831b8f16dc0b). The puzzle is about encrypting messages using the following C++ code:

```
int main()
{
  int size;

  cin >> size;

  unsigned int* a = new unsigned int[size / 16]; // <- input tab to encrypt
  unsigned int* b = new unsigned int[size / 16]; // <- output tab

  for (int i = 0; i < size / 16; i++) {   // Read size / 16 integers to a
    cin >> hex >> a[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < size / 16; i++) {   // Write size / 16 zeros to b
    b[i] = 0;
  } 

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      b[(i + j) / 32] ^= ( (a[i / 32] >> (i % 32)) &
               (a[j / 32 + size / 32] >> (j % 32)) & 1 ) << ((i + j) % 32);   // Magic centaurian operation
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < size / 16; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      cout << ' ';
    }
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(8) << hex << b[i];       // print result
  }
  cout << endl;

 /* 
    Good luck humans     
 */
  return 0;
}
```

The objective is to reverse this encoding (that should be a known mathematical operation when identified). The problem i'm facing is that i cannot understand what the encoding works and what all these binary operations are doing. Can you explain me how this encoding works?

Thank you!

Comment: It should use vectors to avoid leaking memory.

Comment: Have you studied binary operations ( shift, or, and ) in C/C++ ?

Comment: it's part of an ongoing challenge on codingame. Cheating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To learn what the operations are, break it down loop-by-loop and line-by-line, then apply the rules of precedence. Nothing more, nothing less. If I haven't lost track somewhere in the bitwise swamp, the effect of which all boils down to `exclusive XOR`'ing the orignal value at index `b[(i + j) / 32]` by a `power of 2` in the range of a signed integer (or `0`). The analysis would look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {

        b[(i + j) / 32] ^= 

        ( (a[i / 32] >> (i % 32)) &

            (a[j / 32 + size / 32] >> 

            (j % 32)) & 1 ) << 

            ((i + j) % 32);   // Magic centaurian operation
    }
}
```

What is the first operation:

```
 b[(i + j) / 32] ^=
```

This in an `exclusive OR` of the value at that index. If you just let `idx` represent the jumble that computes the index, you can write it as:

```
b[idx] ^= stuff
```

which applying the rules of precedence (`right-to-left` for `^=`) is the same as writing:

```
b[idx] = b[idx] ^ stuff
```

The order of precedence tells us me need to figure out `stuff` before we can apply it to the value of `b[idx]`. Looking at `stuff` you have:

```
  |                          A                        | << |      B      |
  |          C      | & |             D               |    |             |
  |                 |   |          E            | & 1 |    |             |
  +-----------------+---+-----------------------+-----+----+-------------+
  ( (a[i/32]>>(i%32)) & (a[j/32+size/32]>>(j%32)) & 1 ) << ( (i+j) % 32 );
```

Breaking in down, you have `A << B`, which can be further broken down as:

```
( C & D ) << B
```

or finally:

```
(C & E & 1) << B
```

The rules of precedence relevant to `(C & E & 1) << B` are all applied `left-to-right` giving deference to the parenthesis grouping.

So what is `B`? It is just a number that the grouping `(C & E & 1)` will be shifted to the left by. In terms of the index values `i` and `j` modded with the number of bits in an integer, it will simply shift the bits in grouping `(C & E & 1)` to the left by `0-31` bits depending on the combined value of `i+j`.

The grouping `(C & E & 1)` is an entirely similar analysis. `a[i/32]>>(i%32)` is nothing more than the value at `a[i/32]` shifted to the right by `(i%32)`. `E` is the same with slightly differnt index manipulation: `(a[j/32+size/32]>>(j%32))` which is just the value at that index shifted right by `(j%32)`. The result of both of those shifts are then `ANDED` with `1`. What that means is the entire grouping `(C & E & 1)` will only have a value if both `C & E` are `odd` number values.

Why only `odd` values? From a binary standpoint, `odd` numbers are the only values that will have the one-bit `1`. (e.g. `5 & 7 & 1` (`101 & 111 & 1`) = `1`). If any of the values are `even` or `0`, then the whole grouping will be `0`.

Understanding the grouping `(C & E & 1)` (or what we have largely grouped as `A`), you can now look at:

```
A << B
```

Knowing `A` will be `0` or `1`, you know the only way the result of the shift will have value is if `A` is `1`, and then the result of the group will just be the value of `1` shifted left by `B` bits. Knowing `B` has the range of `0-31`, then the range of values for `A << B` are between `0 - 2147483648`, **but** since you are shifting by between `0 - 31`, the values for `A << B` will only be the positive powers of two between `0 - 2147483648` (binary: `0`, `1`, `10`, `100`, `1000`, etc...)

Then that finally brings us to

```
b[idx] = b[idx] ^ stuff
```

which when you `exclusively OR` anything by a power of two, you only serve to flip the bit at the *power of two in that number*. (e.g. `110101` (26) ^ `1000` (8) = `111101` (61)). All other bits are unchanged. So the final effect of all the operations is to make:

```
b[idx] = b[idx] ^ stuff
```

nothing more than:

```
b[idx] = b[idx] ^ (power of two)
```

or

```
b[idx] = b[idx] ^ 0   /* which is nothing more than b[idx] to begin with */
```

Let me know if you have any questions. You can easily dump the index calculations to look at the values, but this should cover the operations at issue.

Comment: Wow! That's a really nice answer. Thank you so much for the time writing this answer piece by piece. The only thing i do not understand is that b[idx] = b[idx] ^ (power of two) === b[idx] = b[idx] ^ 0 . The result wouldn't be b[idx] flipped only in the bit of "power of two"?

Comment: So, another question: Then the operation is idempotent? It just left b[idx] uninvariant under its action?

Comment: No it isn't idempotent. (well, it **may** be only in some combinations of `i` and `j`, but not all). Bits are changing and the value of `b[idx]` can change, so taking its new value after one calculation and plugging it back in again is **NOT** guaranteed to give you to the same `b[idx]`. Univarient? Not by my definition. It depends on the values of `i, j, and b` at any given index combination, so you can't say it depends on one only. It would be torturous to say it depends on `b` only.

Comment: Hmm.. `stuff` above, depending on the values of `a, i & j`, will either be equal to **some power of 2 between** `2^0 - 2^31` or it will be **equal to** `0`. That will result in your final result being `b[idx] = b[idx] ^ (power of two)` **OR** `b[idx] = b[idx] ^ 0`.  (not both at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is doing a **Carry-free Multiplication Operation** on the first half parts of the array (`a[0:size/32]`) and the second half parts of the array (`a[size/32:size/16]`).

I write an equivalent version in binary below the original version, hope this might help you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int size;
  cin >> size;

  unsigned int* a = new unsigned int[size / 16]; // <- input tab to encrypt
  unsigned int* b = new unsigned int[size / 16]; // <- output tab

  bool *a1 = new bool[size];
  bool *a2 = new bool[size];
  bool *bb = new bool[size * 2];

  for (int i = 0; i < size / 16; i++) {   // Read size / 16 integers to a
    cin >> hex >> a[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < size * 2; i++) {
    if (i < size) {
      a1[i] = (a[i / 32] & (1 << (i % 32))) > 0; // first `size` bits are for a1
    } else {
      a2[i - size] = (a[i / 32] & (1 << (i % 32))) > 0; // rest `size` bits are for a2
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < size / 16; i++) {   // Write size / 16 zeros to b
    b[i] = 0;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < size * 2; i++) {
    bb[i] = 0;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      b[(i + j) / 32] ^= ( (a[i / 32] >> (i % 32)) &
               (a[j / 32 + size / 32] >> (j % 32)) & 1 ) << ((i + j) % 32);   // Magic centaurian operation
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      bb[i + j] ^= (a1[i] & a2[j] & 1); // some operation as multiply (*) do
    }

  for(int i = 0; i < size / 16; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      cout << ' ';
    }
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(8) << hex << b[i];       // print result
  }
  cout << endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < size / 32 * 2; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      cout << ' ';
    }
    unsigned int hex_number = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) hex_number += bb[i * 32 + j] << j;
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(8) << hex << hex_number; // print result
  }
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! The Carry-free mult. operation could be expressed in terms of a convolution or something similar?